# Configuration Manager Powershell Module Move-CMObject Error

Tags: powershell, sccm, configurationmanager

I am using a Powershell Module (ConfigurationManager) to create config manager applications etc.

The applications  are created successfully in the root folder and I want to move them to another folder.

When using the following Powershell

```
$appObject = Get-CMAppliction -Name "theApplication"

Move-CMObject -FolderPath "AB1:\Application\TestFolder" -InputObject $appObject
```

I recieve the following error:

> Cannot bind parameter -InputObject.  Cannot convert the
> "[SecurityVerbs (-1)]"

Any ideas?

Thanks

I have also tried moving an application that was created manually using the script (same error), also the folder does exist in the correct location.

Comment: I could not really reproduce this in my environment, it works fine for me. Does this happen when you just connect to the server via ps and paste those two lines, or in some complex script? Maybe as a workaround you could try by not using the inputobject parameter but the objectid. For an application the objectid would be $appObject.CI_UniqueID however without the final slash and number.